# Moving Logic from Directive to Method in Vue Compoment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a VueJS component that targets the style attr like this:

```
<section :style="{ backgroundImage: src && 'url(' + src + ')' }">

...

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['src']
  }
</script>
```

Now, this works exactly as I wish it to (it includes the style attr if the user enters a image url and does not include it if he/she does not.

However, my understanding is that it is 'better' (in general) to separate my logic out into a method rather than include it within the :style directive.

Now, I am fairly new to VueJS and do not have a strong JavaScript backgrand and am trying to figure out how to do that, but have not been able.

As such, I'm wondering if someone could show me how to write a method (or some other recommend best practice) to achieve the same result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't really need a method, you could simply use a computed property.

```
computed:{
  sectionStyle(){
    return {
      backgroundImage: this.src && `url(${this.src})`
    }
  }
}
```

And use it in your template like so:

```
<section :style="sectionStyle">
```

You would use a method if you had arguments that determine the style, as you might in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

@Bert answer got me on the right track, but for some reason it didn't work as expected.  I slightly modified it and then everything worked fine.  Here is my modification:

```
<section :style="bgSrc">
...
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['src'],
    computed: {
      bgSrc () {
        if (this.src) {
          return { backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.src + ')' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```